# How to establish communication between ViewModels of the same screen in SwiftUI MVVM

Tags: swiftui, mvvm

In my app, I have a Screen with Toolbar and Main View.

```
VStack {
    ToolbarView()
    MainView()
}
```

Think of it like this:

[image]

Toolbar has its own View and ToolbarViewModel where we can select “Tools”

```
struct ToolbarView: View {
    @StateObject private var VM = ToolbarViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Toolbar View")
    }
}

@MainActor final class ToolbarViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var selectedTool: Int = 1
    
    func selectTool() {
        //We select a new tool
        selectedTool = 2
    }
}
```

Main view has its own View and MainViewModel

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject private var VM = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Main View")
    }
}

@MainActor final class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var selectedTool: Int = 1
}
```

Now, when I tap a button in the ToolbarView and call a function in ToolbarViewModel to select a new tool, the tool must change in the MainViewModel too.

What would be the correct way of implementing this?

Comment: View models should never talk to each other, they shouldn’t know about each other.

Answer (score 1):

In the screen with the MainView and ToolbarView instances, create @StateObject(s) for both

```
@StateObject private var mainVM = MainViewModel()
@StateObject private var toolbarVM = ToolbarViewModel()
```

Then, create Observed objects in both your instances:
ToolbarView:

```
struct ToolbarView: View {
    @ObservedObject var VM: ToolbarViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Toolbar View")
    }
}
```

MainView:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var VM: MainViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Main View")
    }
}
```

Then pass your objects in the screen than you created your instances:

```
VStack {
    ToolbarView(VM: toolbarVM)
    MainView(VM: mainVM)
}
```

Finally, whenever you make a change you can just listen to it like:

```
VStack {
    ToolbarView(VM: toolbarVM)
    MainView(VM: mainVM)
}
.onChange(of: toolbarVM.isDrawing) { newValue in {
   mainVM.isDrawing = newValue
}
.onChange(of: mainVM.isDrawing) { newValue in {
   toolbarVM.isDrawing = newValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI. The `View` data struct is already the view model that SwiftUI uses to create/update/remove `UIView` objects automatically for us. The property wrappers give the struct reference semantics giving us the best of both worlds. You'll have to learn `@State` and `@Binding` and put the shared state in a parent `View`, then pass it down as a `let` for read access or `@Bindng var` for write access, e.g.

```
@State var tools = Tools() 
...
VStack {
    ToolbarView(tools: $tools)
    MainView(tools: tools)
}

struct Tools {
    var selectedTool: Int = 1
    
    mutating func selectTool() {
        //We select a new tool
        selectedTool = 2
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    let tools: Tools
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Main View \(tools.selected)")
    }
}

struct ToolbarView: View {
    @Binding var tools: Tools
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Toolbar View")
        Button("Select") {
            tools.selectTool()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, I’ll see what I can do with that. One thing bothering me is that I have >1500 lines of code in my current ViewModel. And the View contains only SwiftUI view code. I can refactor a lot of it. But still, around 800 lines of code and multiple methods will go to the View. Isn't that considered bad practice?

Comment: In SwiftUI the View data struct isn’t the view in the MVC sense